# Why does sqlite's delete always succeed, even when the row to delete does not exist?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

After I create a table, insert data into it, and then delete a non-existent row, the operation succeeds even though the row does not exist. When I delete a row that actually exists, it succeeds as well and the row is actually deleted. Why doesn't an error occur when I try to delete a row that does not exist?

I am using sqlite3 with c++ on eclipse.
I've been working with some code found on the web, as well as my own. 
Other operations, like SELECT and INSERT work fine. DELETE works when rows exist and even when they don't exist.

// Creating a table

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE COMPANY("  \
"ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
"NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL," \
"AGE            INT     NOT NULL," \
"ADDRESS        CHAR(50)," \
"SALARY         REAL );";
```

// Inserting data

```
sql = "INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) " \   
"VALUES (1, 'Paul', 32, 'California', 20000.00 ); " \
"INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY) "  \
"VALUES (2, 'Allen', 25, 'Texas', 15000.00 ); "     \
"INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" \
"VALUES (3, 'Teddy', 23, 'Norway', 20000.00 );" \
"INSERT INTO COMPANY (ID,NAME,AGE,ADDRESS,SALARY)" \
"VALUES (4, 'Mark', 25, 'Rich-Mond ', 65000.00 );";
```

// Deleting (this is where the deletion should fail because there is no 
 ID 30)

```
rc = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);

if( rc ) {
    cout << "ERROR ----> " << zErrMsg << endl;
  return(0);
} else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Opened database successfully\n");
}

/* Create SQL statement */
sql = "DELETE FROM COMPANY WHERE ID = 30";

/* Execute SQL statement */
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, (void*)data, &zErrMsg);

if( rc != SQLITE_OK ) {
    cout << "ERROR DELETING" << endl;
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
    sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
} else {
    fprintf(stdout, "Deletion operation done successfully\n");
}
sqlite3_close(db);
```

I expect the message "ERROR DELETING" to be displayed, but "Deletion operation done successfully" always displays, even when the ID deleted does not exist.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but it may be thought of as delete is "ensure this won't exist once the transaction finishes". At the end of the transaction, the record doesn't exist, whether it was deleted or not, and in that regard it has succeeded. If you need to know whether it existed or not, you can simply check. The same goes for updating or retrieving elements: if no element existed there's no error.

Comment: I also believe this query will succeed if there is a table named COMPANY and it has a ID column regardless if any row matched or not.

Answer (score 6):

**Why doesn't an error occur when I try to delete a row that does not exist?**

Databases return number of rows affected (deleted in your case), they don't throw error, unless there is something wrong with the query.

Comment: The `sqlite3_exec` function returns `SQLITE_OK`, not the number of rows affected.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case **sqlite3_changes()** could be executed immediately after the delete to get number of rows affected.  [Further Information](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html)

Answer (score 2):

The only guaranteed method to check if the row has been deleted is to execute a `SELECT` statement with the same conditions. Transaction control is an important factor here, i.e. what happens if something causes a rollback? Are you explicitly committing transactions, or allowing them to auto-commit? You shouldn't just rely on return codes for this. If you do a `COUNT` as well, then you will know for sure, at least within your session:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM COMPANY WHERE ID = 30
```

If after the `DELETE`, the `COUNT` is `0`, the row no longer exists.

**Note**: This approach will be helpful if you need concurrency, which will force you to use a different database engine (e.g. PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer is "this is by design".

If you need to know if zero (or more) rows were affected by the last DELETE statement (or INSERT or UPDATE for that matter) then you could look into using:

```
int sqlite3_changes(sqlite3*);
```

That will allow you to react accordingly if no rows were deleted.

See https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/changes.html